# How do lightgbm encode categorial features?

Tags: lightgbm

I have the following structure of one lightGbm tree:
{'split_index': 0,
'split_feature': 41,
'split_gain': 97.25859832763672,
'threshold': '3||4||8',
'decision_type': '==',
'default_left': False,
'missing_type': 'None',
'internal_value': 0,
'internal_weight': 0,
'internal_count': 73194,
'left_child': {'split_index': 1,
and the feature in 0 node is categorial and I feed this feature in format "category".
where can I find the appropriate between number format and category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers you see are the values of the `codes` attribute of your categorical features. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'], dtype='category')
print(s.cat.codes)
# 0    0
# 1    1
# 2    0
# 3    0
# 4    1
# dtype: int8
```

so in this case `0` is `a` and `1` is `b`.
You can build a mapping from the category code to the value with something like the following:

```py
dict(enumerate(s.cat.categories))
# {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}
```

If the categories in your column don't match the ones in the model, LightGBM will update them.